# create AWS resources depending on parameter value

Tags: amazon-web-services, conditional-statements, aws-cloudformation

I want to create AWS resources depending on the condition in CloudFormation. The condition is depending on the parameter value such that if the parameter value is null then do not create AWS resources. If I provide value to the parameter then only AWS resources should be created. Parameter's value coming from variable like below.

Can I use AWS::NoValue in the condition section such that if an S3_NAME is null, do not create aws resources? or not sure how should I go about with this one.

```
Conditions:
  CreateS3Alerts:
    Fn::Not
      - ${self:custom.config.S3_NAME}
      - AWS::NoValue

S35xxErrors:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Condition: CreateS3Alerts
    Properties:
      AlarmName: "S3 5XX Errors"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** do this. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) in your conditions you **can only use**:

> another condition, a parameter value, or a mapping

A common pattern with conditions is to use [Equals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-equals), which checks if you have **empty string**:

```
Conditions:
  CreateS3Alerts:
    !Not [!Equals [${self:custom.config.S3_NAME}, ""]]
```

Comment: woked for me. Also, Why the triple nots? doesn't it work with just [!Equals[...]]? although we need quotes around '${self:custom.config.S3_NAME}'. Thank you for the help :) @Marcin

Comment: Confusingly, [exclamation points are not nots in CloudFormation. Exclamation points are the syntax for functions themselves](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html)